# Alert or Commands or Notification if Quantity increase or Decrease in magento?

Tags: magento, magento-1.8, magento-1.6

i need to get Alert or Commands or Notification message if Quantity increase or Decrease in magento? i am the new guy in magento?How to configure on this?

Answer (score 1):

There only is an RSS feed notifying you if the quantity drops belowe a certain level. You would need to find or create an extension if you want a more sophisticated behavior.

Such an extension could be based on something like this:

You hook into the `cataloginventory_stock_item_save_after` event like this:

```
<events>
    <cataloginventory_stock_item_save_after>
        <observers>
            <package_module_stocknote>
                <type>singleton</type>
                <class>Package_Module_Model_Observer</class>
                <method>stocknote</method>
            </package_module_stocknote>
        </observers>
    </cataloginventory_stock_item_save_after>       
</events>
```

Then create an observer at `Package/Module/Model/Observer.php`:

```
class Package_Module_Model_Observer extends Varien_Event_Observer {
    public function stocknote($observer) {
        $stockItem = $observer->getEvent()->getItem();
        //Insert your logic here
    }   
}
```

Comment: i need to get alert message for every product when it will increase  or Decrease coz admin guy know why and what for adding product or decreasing product?

Comment: This event will be fired every time a product (or rather, the related stock item) will be saved. Whether the amount changed or not you could check by getOrigData() or something. I am not entirely sure what your problem is and what you are asking.

Comment: yes you are correct.. so need to call getOrigData() function in which file?

Comment: i think `cataloginventory_stock_item_save_after` this will not work on frontend